# How to increase the value in each list item by a specific value kotlin

Tags: android, algorithm, kotlin

For example, i have a code:

```
data class Item(
    val value: Int
)

val list = mutableListOf(
    Item(0),
    Item(10),
    Item(20)
)
```

You need to make sure that each element in the list changes its value by a certain number.

I came up with this way:

```
list.forEachIndexed { index, item ->  
        when(index) {
            0 -> {
                item.value + 10
            }
            1 -> {
                item.value + 20
            }
            2 -> {
                item.value + 30
            }
        }
    }
```

However, this method is not very suitable, because if there are 100,000 elements in the list, then you don’t really want to process each one manually. How can this be done more correctly?

Comment: maybe `item.value + (index + 1) * 10` ?

Comment: How did you get these 10, 20, 30 values? Are they always just multiplications of 10?

Comment: @broot You have the right remark. IR42's answer is correct, but I took the numbers 10 20 30 by accident, there can be absolutely any numbers, and then the IR42's method with multiplication by 10 will not work, i need a more adaptive solution

Comment: "They can be absolutely any numbers"...then it depends on their source. Do you have a List of these other numbers? Your `forEachIndexed` function is not doing anything because it has no side effects. It's just declaring numbers and releasing them immediately. There is no functional operator for modifying a MutableList in place provided by the standard library, so you'd either want to make your own or simply use a for loop.

Comment: `item.value + 10` does not modify the `Item`, the way you defined it, it is immutable. If you want to change the `Item` you need to have `var value: Int` and then `item.value += 10`

Comment: What do you mean "there can be absolutely any numbers"? Where do they come from? If they're stored in another list, you could use the *index* to pull the appropriate value from that, or you could `zip` the two lists to get an *item* and *adjustmentValue* you can use in the lambda (more useful if you're using `map` instead of mutating a list though). Easiest way is probably `list.indices.forEach { i -> list[i] += adjustments[i] }`. If there's anything more complicated than that going on, you'll have to tell us what's actually happening!